# Max height or width of an image inside a div while keeping proportions in pure css

Tags: css

I have two layouts, but they are conceptually the same.

One is a div containing an image. The other is two floating div elements that takes half with of their parent div at the left and right respectively containing an image each. Their parent div size and proportion depends of the body size and proportions and it is unknow until display time, so I need to specify it by percentage and not by constant width or height.
In both cases I need the maximum width or height while keeping aspect ratio and not overflowing the parent div, so image/s display as bigger as possible while keeping proportion.

I know how to keep proportions with max height or with, but not with both, so there is overflow. I also know how to accomplish this with Javascript, but I'm trying to avoid scripts in my layout and I want to handle that in css.

I haven't see anything like that in the net, nor googling gave me a clue about it, so I even doubt if this is actually possible in css.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT :

OK, I figured out how to do it. The deal was setting up image max-height and max-width to 100%. However I am facing another problem, so I post the layout if someone doing what I was trying to do finds it useful, and I remake the question to focus in the new problem.

Here's the layout. It will keep images aspect ration to the biggest possible size.

index.html

```
<html> 
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div id="pageleft" class="page">
            <img src="img/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="pageright" class="page">
            <img src="img/2.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.header{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:2em;
}

 .page{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
 }

 #pageright{
    float:right;
    background-color:green;
 }

 #pageleft{
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
 }

.page > img{
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

#pageleft > img {
    right:0;
}
#pageright > img {
    left:0;
}
```

Note 1: Tested in Chrome and Firefox both desktop (resizing the window to any size/propotion) and mobile (portrait and landscape).

Note 2: I'm using A paper cut proportions for the images, but should work with any image size and proportions, even when both images have different aspect ratio.

The problem is that my header height is 2em and that is what the .page div are overflowing. Does anyone know a way to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get the ball rolling and ask a more specific question. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, I'll try to improve the question.

Comment: If you figured out an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Sure. Then should I open a new thread for the new question?

Comment: I was missing the max-width and max-height of image to set it to 100%. And now it fits. Thank you.